# Magento 2 Search terms shows Chinese word

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-1.7

We have developed a Magento 2 site. For last few weeks search term in admin panel shows Chinese words as below

1. 바카라사이트¶ ( ―▷ 79ASK，CoM ◁― )
   ¶33카지노바카라사이트33카지노바카라사이트33카지노바카라사이트33카지노바카라사이트33카지노바카라사이트33카지노바카라사이트33카지노
2. 大奖娱乐HB老虎机送彩金www.djyl18.com
3. 趣拍娱乐MG老虎机开户 www.qpyl18.com
4. 大奖老虎机优惠红利 Q82019309.com.com

[image: Searches term in Magento admin panel]

Please, can anyone explain why the Chinese word exists in Magento search term?help me to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically this search terms shows **latest search keyword** by customer on your website.

> **So if some one has pass this "Chinese" string into your frontend**
>   **search box it will display at backend as well.**
>
> **Even though same thing will happen in Default Magento as well , if you**
>   **pass at frontend this string!**

So might be some customer has passed this "Chinese" string at frontend and you will see here at backend.

**But on a security note - you need to check your website security , to confirm there is not BOT detection which does same action.**

Comment: Thank you @manthan Dave. We have investigated the problem based on bot detection. Now, we have fixed the issue.

Comment: @Pari.J , Can you please share, How did you solved? did you applied js in searchbox, that Chinese Characters are not accepted?

Answer (score 0):

It's not always as simple as this, I've seen it where inbound links have been crawled by Google that are sent to the search results page. These links carry search terms and are effectively spam inbound links. You can read more [here](https://www.citricmedia.co.uk/magento-2-fix-chinese-search-terms-showing-in-your-dashboard/)